# Stop at the end of a track

Tags: motor

I would like to create a camera dolly for capturing timelapse movies.

i.e. something like this:
http://youtu.be/Qce1f6SKEMU

Whats a reliable way to detect the end of the track and stop the stepper motor moving the camera? In other words how is it possible to get the current position of the camera and stop the motor before the track ends to prevent crashing into the bumpers?

Comment: Many thanks for all of your answers. I think I need to get familiar with all of the mentioned methods to finally decide what's the best for my project.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to have an opto-interrupter fitted at one end of the track (IR LED and IR Phototransistor), and a small bit of plastic or whatever on the dolly which interrupts the IR beam.

Printers have been doing it that way with their print heads for decades.

http://www.martyncurrey.com/connecting-an-photo-interrupter-to-an-arduino/

Answer (score 1):

I find a mechanical switch the simplest and cheapest. But technically it is the same as an opto switch.  These are often refered to as [limit switches](https://www.google.com/search?q=limit%20switch&tbm=isch).

[image]

You tie the switch to a pin with the normally closed (NC) pin, set it to pinMode(pullup), and check it each each loop. When the read value goes low (0), you stop moving your motor.

Answer (score 1):

Many methods exist:

References to unpowered means the switch does not draw power when not operated. When a motor is activated it will draw power.

- Mechanical switch- microswitch is the most common (as per Spiked3's suggestion). Contamination and weather may be issues (depending on how waterproof your camera is). No power needed for actual switch.
- Optical (a la Majenko). Some environmental issues. Effect of ambient light needs to be considered.
- Capacitive. Can be fully sealed. Need to be powered.
- Magnetic - Hall (powered) and Reed (unpowered).

Whatever is used, the current and voltage ratings need to be compatible with the load. In many cases the actual switch will need a transistor or relay or similar to provide the power drive to the dolly motor. This is not hard to do but needs to be noted.

---

An end of track signalling method that is relatively unaffected by environmental issues is to use a magnet and magnet detector. The most common detectors are either a "Hall sensor" IC or a reed switch.

Reed switches are mechanical and more fragile than Hall sensors but need no power when unoperated and can be bought in ready made encapsulations that are robust enough to be reliable. Properly implemented a reed switch can be essentially indestructible.

Hall sensors need to be powered but power levels are small compared to eg dolly motor current and low current versions are available.

Both Hall sensors and reed switches have a degree of "hysteresis" - the point in the travel where they operate is past the point where they release again, but this is easily allowed for in practice.

---

[Reed switch demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnCEQYO-i_E) - 38 seconds video - simple and obvious.

Instructables [DIY powered dolly wity reed swithes](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-motorized-moving-timelapse-camera-dolly-with-A/all/)

[Sparkfun magnetic door switch set](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13247) and encapsulated reed switch and magnet.

[Hall sensor theory of operation](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/electromagnetism/hall-effect.html)

[Many ideas here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=hall+sensor&biw=1280&bih=789&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=buRtVYmRFtXh8AWv9YOYAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=hall+effect+sensor++circuit) for using hall sensors.

[Reed switches](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=hall+sensor&biw=1280&bih=789&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=buRtVYmRFtXh8AWv9YOYAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=reed+switch+)